# Ayúdenme a planear una conferencia de SOes

Tags: discusión

Necesito ayuda al planear nuestra primera conferencia de SOes.  Esta es una idea que no esta garantizada pero necesito investigar lo necesario antes de proponerla a la empresa.  Siendo que estamos esparcidos por todo el mundo, me gustaría saber lo siguiente:

- ¿En que país deberíamos tener la conferencia? Recuerden que necesitamos un lugar central donde la máxima cantidad de gente pueda asistir.
- ¿Que temas les interesan?
- ¿Hay algún desarrollador de habla hispana que les gustaría escuchar en vivo?

Para poder opinar, por favor den sus opiniones en las siguientes páginas:

[Para opinar en el país, haz clic aquí.](https://goo.gl/forms/nGUVRajptMpy5Pva2)

[Para opinar sobre los temas, haz clic aquí.](https://goo.gl/forms/iyJL8a95R7yB1ABs1)

[Para opinar sobre los panelistas, haz clic aquí.](https://goo.gl/forms/eZMGBoeXmb2MNlsJ3)

Comment: Ya está, pueden intentar de nuevo. :)

Comment: En el de los países, ¿deberíamos votar por los países en los que pudiesemos asistir o los que creemos que son mejores para la conferencia (por que tengan mayor representación o una comunidad más establecida)?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Ok, ya está corregido la de los temas.  Para la de los países, vota para los que tu prefieras usando el criterio que desees.

Comment: Mucha suerte con la conferencia, ojalá pueda participar :)

Comment: ¿Hay algún desarrollador de habla hispana que les gustaría escuchar en vivo? [**Miguel de Icaza**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miguel_de_Icaza)